# Matlab doesn't recognize user environmental variable

Tags: matlab, environment-variables, ubuntu-22.04

I installed an application named `lqns` in the path: `/home/robb/Research/dist/lqns-6.2/lqns` (`lqns` is a folder containing the executable `lqns`). I want the program to be executed in command line simply calling `lqns` in the shell, I solved this adding to the file `~/.bashrc` the line:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/robb/Research/dist/lqns-6.2/lqns
```

And it works with no issue. I am now trying to execute this program inside a Matlab script, running:

```
[status, ~] = system("lqns " + filename, '-echo');
```

Where `filename` is the path of an input file. I get the error message:

```
/bin/bash: line 1: lqns: command not found
```

Running the exact same command with the shell I get no error: the program runs with no problem generating the relative output.

Running `getenv('PATH');` in Matlab and `printenv PATH` on my OS shell I indeed get two different results: Matlab does't have the path to `lqns`. I even tried editing manually the files `/etc/environment`, `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `/root/.bashrc`, with no result. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Try putting the `PATH` export command in your `~/.profile` file instead. `~/.bashrc` is only for interactive shells, and MATLAB does not start an interactive bash shell, so it will not be loaded.

Answer (score 1):

you need to launch matlab by typing `matlab` in a terminal, not by double clicking on its shortcut from your desktop. (or even typing `./matlab` in a terminal from your desktop)

it's up to the operating system to determine what double clicking does, and it's not guaranteed to execute most of your shell initialization scripts (or even launch it from the correct shell to begin with).

more info at [Why are environment variables not resolved when double-clicking .desktop file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/592464)